# question from capacitors

Tags: dielectric

A capacitor of capacitance 1uf withstands maximum voltage 6kv while a capacitor of 2uf withstands maximum voltage 4kv. What maximum voltage will the system of two capacitor withstands if they are connected in series?
Someone help I am not getting where to start.

Comment: What is the voltage divider rule for capacitors? Do you know it? That is a starting point.

Comment: Should be very careful with that. If it's not a. Homework, putting capacitors in series is a serious pain in the neck. You would need balancing circuits to guarantee the charge is actually balanced between them.

Comment: Mkeith voltage divider rule not in syllabus

Comment: Wait... if the voltage divider is not on your syllabus, that means that this is probably a physics class and not an _electrical engineering_ class. [Here's some info on the voltage divider between two capacitors](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap_7.html).

Comment: Didn't helped. here the breakdown voltage is different for eACH capacitor

Comment: @Robo, let's say we put the two capacitors in series and apply 1V to them. What is the voltage across each of them? Knowing how to figure that out is the first step.

Comment: We find the equivalence capictance and find current as same current flows through them. Then voltage across capacitor = current / capacitance of that capacitor

Comment: See if the link below or other similar can point you in the correct direction.  -  http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap_7.html

Comment: doesn't matter that it's different. the first one that fails is the important one.

Answer (score 2):

Since both capacitors will be connected in series, the same current flows through both. Assuming they were connected in series while they were both discharged, then both have the same charge \$Q\$.

Then, given their capacitances, you have a relation between the voltage on each capacitor, and you can calculate the voltage on a capacitor when the other one reaches its maximum voltage. Then you can conclude about the maximum voltage for the set.

Answer (score 1):

$$C = \frac {Q} {V}$$

You know maximum voltage for each capacitor.  Work out charge for each capacitor.

When connected in series, both capacitors will experience the same charge (since charge is proportional to current), which means the series combination is limited by maximum voltage due to the smallest charge.

Take the smallest Q (well you could do both).  Apply it to second capacitor to get it's voltage.  Add this to the maximum of the other capacitor to get maximum system voltage.